# PHP Best separator

Tags: php, explode

I am working on a script in which we need to allow a user to upload bulk amount of orders using a text file.

Upon receiving the file, the php script will split the lines into pieces using a pipe character (|) as the separator.

This is done using

`$data = explode("|", $line);`

`12/22/2014|210|S|L|My Job Name1|123456|16308|100||12/30/2014|Must go by FedEx`

Now, this works fine, but the clients don't want to use | character. They want to use a comma.

For example

`12/22/2014,210,S,L,My Job Name1,123456,16308,100,,12/30/2014,Must go by FedEx`

This is fine as long as there is no comma present in between the job name field.

Consider this "My, Job Name1" -as the job name. In this case, the line  would be

`12/22/2014,210,S,L,My, Job Name1,123456,16308,100,,12/30/2014,Must go by FedEx`

which would be exploded incorrectly by PHP.

Is there any better way to achieve this using comma ?

Comment: If they want to use a comma, why not? [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a data file format that has been around for years; and PHP provides functions like [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for reading it

Comment: Also, most popular spreadsheet programs support CSV.

Comment: The standard is to wrap string values in quotes (typically `"`) so that a comma (delimiter) within a string value is easily recognisable; and quotes within a string value can also be escaped

Comment: Also, it requires minimal tongue work to pronounce "CSV".

Answer (score 1):

Ask them for some real data so you can make an informed decision. You might think there is a low chance of collision for pipe symbols, but the last place I worked at, a team in a different office started using the character as part of their naming convention for projects. This broke many things.

Also see if you can trace back the data to where it is originally entered into the system, there may be some validation on it at this point. Any illegal characters will presumably be fair game for you to use.